# Ionic google map, How to set the position on the marker?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I added google maps in my app, and created a marker, but when i open the view, I get my current position on the screen.

What I want is when google maps open, the position to be on the marker.
 I am using cordova-plugin-geolocation.

UPDATE CODE

```
.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http, $cordovaGeolocation) {
    /// Main map
    this.Tool = function() {
            var markers = [];
    $scope.id= sessionStorage.getItem('product_info_id');
    var str="http://www.manaspp.hol.es/markers.php?product_id="+$scope.id;
        $http.get(str).then(function (response){
          markers = response;
          console.log(markers);
        var records = markers.data.markers;
        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) 
        {
          var record = records[i];   
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(record.lat, record.lng);
    var mapOptions = {
      center: myCenter,
      zoom: 15,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    };
           $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
     google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($scope.map, 'idle', function(){  
            loadMarkers();
         });
        }
     }); 


  // Marker loading use php script
    function loadMarkers(){  
    var markers = [];
    $scope.id= sessionStorage.getItem('product_info_id');
    var str="http://www.manaspp.hol.es/markers.php?product_id="+$scope.id;
        $http.get(str).then(function (response){
          markers = response;
          console.log(markers);
        var records = markers.data.markers;
        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) 
        {
          var record = records[i];   
          var markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(record.lat, record.lng);

          // Add the markerto the map
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: $scope.map,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              position: markerPos
          });
          var infoWindowContent = "<h4>" + record.name + "</h4>";          
          addInfoWindow(marker, infoWindowContent, record);
        }
     });     

     }

     function addInfoWindow(marker, message, record) {

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: message
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
          infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
      });
    }
    window.location.href = "#/page10";
    }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Map will be centered to your marker applied. i.e. **myCenter**

```
    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("googleMap");
    var mapOptions = {
      center: myCenter,
      zoom: 8,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:myCenter});
    marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
     zoom: 8,
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
     animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
     labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 38),
     labelClass: "markLabelsJob",
     labelInBackground: false,
     icon: 'img/rsz_active-job-pin.png',
     map: map
   });
```

Comment: Hm, my market loaded across php script which returns a query and i add $scope.id. In database plased id object, and coordinates(lat,lng).

Comment: whats the problem? I couldn't understand.

Comment: Very thanks! But i realized it this way(updated post). I understand that it is a curve, perhaps illogical, but it works)) Maybe you have ideas how to do it better?)

Comment: I have worked on google maps for a while now, I have implemented them on web as well as mobile applications in simple as well as complicated ways as well, I may have ideas but you need to be more specific about the code. share some screenshots how do you want them.

Comment: This code is worked and I'm satisfied with everything. I say for the current code, i think he implemented not very correctly, because i new in programming, and i little blunt)) If you have I will gladly take them into account and get some experience...)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you use your location as map center, also you create multiple markers. 
Create a variable with the latitude and longitude you want the map to be centered and use it like this:

```
var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
var mapOptions = {
  center: mapCenter,
  zoom: 15,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```